# Shorten stack trace of exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a custom exception get raised when someone screws up with my library, which currently looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    StateMachine()
  File "main.py", line 15, in __new__
    activate(self)
  File "/home/runner/va4un94x2qp/fsm.py", line 101, in activate
    state = enable(machine, state)
  File "/home/runner/va4un94x2qp/fsm.py", line 94, in enable
    raise MissingReturnError("State '{}' in machine '{}' missing a return statement, or it returns None..".format(StateFound.fallmsg, machine.__name__))
fsm.MissingReturnError: State '__main__' in machine 'StateMachine' missing a return statement, or it returns None.
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    StateMachine()
  File "main.py", line 15, in __new__
    activate(self)
MissingReturnError: State '__main__' in machine 'StateMachine' missing a return statement, or it returns None.
```

How do I do that, without any excepthook nonsense? (Because **THAT** doesn't just affect one exception, it affects all exceptions) I want to modify an exception. By the way, I've tried setting **suppress_context** to True, I've tried raising the exception from None. How else do I do it?

And if you ask, everything I want gone, isn't needed. All that is needed is the exception message, and the call of the activate() method.

And I'm not going to be messing with the Python interpreter, I'm going to be releasing this library to the public, and I want exceptions to look this way to everyone. (It's Python 3.X)

Comment: Unless you want to build an extension module just for this, you're not going to have much luck.

Comment: pretty much the only way to do what you want is to build custom error handling into your code. You could build a specific internal error class and when certain types of errors get raise, build out pieces in a way that you want them.

Comment: Why is the exception *needed* at all? If there is no error in the code there should be no exception. If you want to enforce that a function returns a specific type maybe you should look into static type checking.